# Angular boostrap: ngbDropdown/ngbDropdownToggle and accessibilty?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, accessibility, ng-bootstrap

We use Bootstrap 4 menus in on site nav.  We'd like to be able to optionally use ng-bootstrap dropdowns as well.

You can turn DS ones into NGB ones with their directive, as so:

```
<li class="nav-item" ngbDropdown>
  <a class="nav-link" ngbDropdownToggle role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu 2</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu ngbfade" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink" ngbDropdownMenu>
    <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="">Menu Item 1</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="">Menu Item 2</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="">Menu Item 3</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

However, with this setup users cannot tab to the menu nor open is and tab/arrowkey to the options like they can with a regular Bootstrap menu.

The code on the ng-bootstrap site yields very different HTML, which is more of drop-button than a link menu:

```
<div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic1" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle dropdown</button>
  <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1">
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Action - 1</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Another Action</button>
    <button ngbDropdownItem>Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make the directive version respond to tabbing?

I tried adding an `href` but of course with Angular that make a click take you to the app home page.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the acronym DS in your question?

Comment: I meant to say BS (Bootstrap)